# Second RMySQL operation fails - why?

Tags: mysql, r

I am running a script that stores different datasets to a MySQL database. This works so far, but only sequentially. e.g.:

```
# write table1 
replaceTable(con,tbl="table1",dframe=dframe1)

# write table2 
replaceTable(con,tbl="table2",dframe=dframe2)
```

If I select both (I use StatET / Eclipse) and run the selection, I get an error:

```
Error in function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function "dbWriteTable",
  for signature "MySQLConnection", "data.frame", "data.frame".
```

I guess this has to do with the fact that my con is still busy or so when the second request is started. When I run the script line after line it just works fine. Hence I wonder, how can I tell R to wait til the first request is ready and then go ahead ? How can I make R scripts interactive (just console like plot examples - no tcl/tk).

EDIT:

```
require(RMySQL)

replaceTable <- function(con,tbl,dframe){
  if(dbExistsTable(con,tbl)){
    dbRemoveTable(con,tbl)
    dbWriteTable(con,tbl,dframe)    
    cat("Existing database table updated / overwritten.")
  }
  else {
    dbWriteTable(con,tbl,dframe)
    cat("New database table created")
  }  
}
```

Comment: Where has the replaceTable function come from?  It's not in the DBI Interface!

Comment: try `help("replaceTable")`, or second best, get the source - type `replaceTable`.

Comment: what's the output when you run it?  move the cat to above the invocation.  add a print statement before the dbWriteTable: `print(dbWriteTable(...))`.  perhaps one of the two functions is failing.

Comment: The error is odd, given what you have written there.  It suggests you have called it with argument 2 is a dataframe as well as argument 3.

Comment: @Alex Brown, there won't be any help because I've written this crap on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dbWriteTable` has two important arguments:

```
overwrite: a logical specifying whether to overwrite an existing table
          or not.  Its default is ‘FALSE’.

  append: a logical specifying whether to append to an existing table
          in the DBMS.  Its default is ‘FALSE’.
```

For past project I have successfully achieve appending, overwriting, creating, ... of tables with proper combinations of these.

Comment: That's my problem so often. I write my own functions for some task and realize later on that there's already a default solution or at least one in another package.